# Android Studio indexing files out of project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is happening with Android Studio Arctic Fox, Bumblebee, and Chipmunk. I think it might be a setting from my IDE settings files.

Indexing takes forever all the time, and I noticed that Android Studio indexes all the files of the SSD (outside of the project), that doesn't seem right.

Is there any setting in Android Studio to scope indexing only to the project files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the best solution but I ended up deleting the '.idea' folder out of my project and it solved the issue.

I'm pretty unfamiliar with Android Studio so I'm not sure if this is an extreme solution.